# How to find out if Mac-Filtering is active on a router

Tags: wifi, mac-spoofing

As mentioned in the title, my question is if it's possible to find out when a wifi router has mac filtering activated for e.g. by airmon-ng or other tools?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you mean the type of MAC filtering that determines whether a device can associate with a network at all, not the type of filtering used by e.g. captive portals to allow or deny internet access based on MAC address.

I don't think there is any way to interrogate an access point for that information. However, you may be able to logically deduce whether it is enabled.

1. Using a random MAC address, attempt to connect to the network with valid credentials. If you are able to connect, there is no MAC filtering.
2. If you are not able to connect, there may be MAC filtering. You can confirm this by monitoring what devices are connected to the network, and by trying to connect using one of their MAC addresses. If you are now able to connect, then you can likely confirm that there is MAC filtering.

Comment: I mean, if an attacker is able to see when my wifi router has mac filtering active to bypass the filtering easily. When he looks for wifi connection on his device he sees many APs to connect to. He hasn't the valid credentials for my network. So he could only guess if he can connect to my wifi by using a connected MAC, right?

Comment: Well, it depends on exactly when the whitelist is enforced; i.e. if the very first frame sent to the AP is rejected, you may not need to know the credentials. But you'd probably have to look at a monitor mode capture to figure this out. No matter what though, MAC filtering can be defeated.